# Passing an argument to a function error type 13

Tags: excel, vba, function, arguments

I am currently getting a type 13 error because a function seems to be getting a wrong argument. What am I doing wrong?

Sheet 1 function (when the sub calls this function it generates a type 13 error):

```
Function extrapolatendg(row As Range) As Integer

extrapolatendg = Range("b" & row).Value

End Function
```

Sheet 6 function:

```
Function findrownumberndg(extrapolatendg As Integer)

Set foundcell = Range("a:a").Find(extrapolatendg, lookat:=xlWhole)

If Not foundcell Is Nothing Then

findrownumberndg = 0

Else

findrownumberndg = foundcell.row

End If

End Function
```

thisworkbook sub actioning functions

```
Sub getndg()

For x = 6 To sheet1lastrow()

Dim currentRow As Range
Set currentRow = Sheet1.Rows(x)

extraolatendg = Sheet1.extrapolatendg(currentRow)

Sheet6.findrownumberndg (extrapolatendg)

Next

End Sub
```

I would expect the extrapolatendg function to take the cell value and pass it to the findrownumberndg in order to return the row number in another sheet.

Comment: I doubt your function has a worksheet parent: `Sheet1.extrapolatendg(currentRow)` should probably be just `extrapolatendg(currentRow)`

Comment: If `row` is a `Range`, you can't do `Range("b" & row)`.

Comment: Also `Function extrapolatendg(row As Range) As Integer` will throw an error if the value is not an `Integer`.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this function does what you think it does. Here's is what it's doing

```
Function extrapolatendg(row As Range) As Integer
    'This is a function, it will do a calculation and return a value.
    ' It's name is extrapolatendg, 
     '(it accepts a range object (either a single cell or a block of cells) and calls that range "row") 
     'It will return an Integer value

     extrapolatendg = Range("b" & row).Value
     'since the object called row is being used in a context that expects a value, 
      'VBA will use the default property of the object - in this case the Value property
     'Find the Value property of the range called row 
     'if row is a single cell and has something in it that can be interpreted as a long then 
    'continue, otherwise throw an error of  "Type Mismatch".
    'Concatenate that long with the letter "b"
    'Pass that string as an argument to the function "Range" - 
    'This will return an object of type "Range"
    'Obtain the value of the "value" property of this object
    'Attempt to coerce this value into an Integer 
    '- if this succeeds, return this value as the result of the function extrapolatendg, 
    'otherwise throw an error "Type Mismatch"

 End Function  'finished
```

Note that in order to use it you must pass the range argument it is expecting, so

```
        Function findrownumberndg(extrapolatendg(Some cell reference goes here) As Integer)
```